# Is integration by parts valid here for this Sobolev function?

Tags: sobolev-spaces

Math people:

This will probably be easy for someone out there.  I have functions $u \in C^\infty([0,1])$, $f \in L^1([0,1])$, and $h(t) = \int_0^t f(s)\,ds$.  Then $h \in W^{1,1}([0,1])$, right?  I'd like to use integration by parts to conclude

$$ \int_0^1 u(t) \frac{d}{dt}(h(t)^2)\,dt = u(t)(h(t))^2|^1_0-\int_0^1 u'(t)(h(t))^2\,dt. $$

Is this valid?  I apologize if this is a duplicate.  I searched for similar questions and couldn't find one.

Comment: Sobolev functions on the line are exactly those functions which have absolutely continuous representatives. Since $f \in L^1$ it follows that $h$ is $AC$, hence in $W^{1,1}$. The integration by parts formula works because $h^2$ is also $AC$.

Comment: Thanks, this helps me understand absolutely continuous functions (I never really understood before why people cared about absolutely continuous functions).  In proofs of Rademacher's Theorem (any Lipschitz function on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is differentiable a.e.), people usually treat the $n=1$ case as obvious - I guess this is because the conclusion of the theorem applies for AC functions (not just Lipschitz).

Comment: Have you found a reference and/or published a paper containing the proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question: Yes, $h \in W^{1,1}(0,1)$ and $h' = f$.

In order to answer questions similar to your second one, density arguments will do a good job:

- Your assertion holds for smooth $h$ (e.g. $h \in C^\infty([0,1])$).
- Since $W^{1,1}(0,1) \hookrightarrow C([0,1])$, all terms in your assertion are continuous w.r.t. the $W^{1,1}(0,1)$-norm of $h$.
- Since $C^\infty([0,1])$ is dense in $W^{1,1}(0,1)$ your assertion follows.

Comment: Thanks.  Do you know of a reference where this is done? Someone has undoubtedly done this before. This will be part of a paper.  I have several options: (i) don't justify the integration by parts and hope that the reviewer believes it; (ii) justify the integration by parts and give your argument; (iii) justify the integration by parts using a reference.  I'll like to use option (iii), since it would save some space.  I can obtain Adams's classic book on Sobolev spaces and Evans's excellent book on PDE easily.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot provide you any reference. However, you could give the above argument abbreviated (i.e., ... which follows by density for all $u \in W^{1,1}(0,1)$.